# Powershell SSH credentials

Tags: powershell, ssh, command

I have this script for automation execute command on multiple machines but appear one problem when I try to force user to enter credential:

```
Write-Host "Enter credentials!" -ForegroundColor Green

$user1 = Read-Host "user"
$pwd1 = Read-Host "pass" -AsSecureString

Write-Host "type command" -ForegroundColor Cyan  
Write-Host "--------------" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host "example: shutdown -f -r -t 0" -ForegroundColor Cyan
$Command1 = Read-Host -Prompt "Comanda"

$Computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Meo\Desktop\ipMachine.txt | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }

foreach($Computer in $Computers){
Write-Host $Computer

    $User = "$user1"
    $pwd1_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd1))
    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd1 -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($User, $secpasswd)

    $Command1 = "$Command"
    Write-Host $Command

Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost

$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credentials -AcceptKey:$true

Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command $Command
}
```

return ( if I put credential in script it works very well..  any ideea? thx)

````
New-SSHSession : Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).
At line:26 char:14
+ ... SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Crede ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (Renci.SshNet.SshClient:SshClient) [New-SSHSession], SshAuthenticationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SSH.NewSshSession
 
Invoke-SSHCommand : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'SessionId' because it is null.
At line:28 char:26
+ Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command $Command
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-SSHCommand], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Invoke-SSHCommand
    ```
````

Comment: You read the password as a secure string - then you unmask it with `PtrToStringAuto` - but then you take the original secure string value and convert it _to a different secure string_. Skip all that and simply construct the credential object from the initial values: `$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user1, $pwd1)`

Comment: I try and doesn't work if I enter credential with Read-Host method. If I put credentials directly in script it works ok, but I want to enter credentials everytime when I start script.

Comment: How about `$Credentials = Get-Credential` then? :)

Comment: I try ... same.

Comment: I found that removing `Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost` could help. I also agree you should use `$Credentials = Get-Credential` and you can safely remove one of the `$Computers = $Computers = ...` here

Comment: Hello Theo, thx again for your help. I try to remove "Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost" and use $Credentials = Get-Credential , also delete "$Computers =" and the return erros is the same.. "New-SSHSession : Permision denied (keyboard-interactive)...

Comment: Any ideea?.....

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem today, and I know it's something about host key verification, but I can't figured out, so my temproray solution is using -Force

> New-SSHSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credentials -AcceptKey -ConnectionTimeout 30 -Force

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).